# Place a line break in note pad

Tags: c#, asp.net, batch-file

I am creating a new text file pro-grammatically.

I am passing a text to batch file to write inside the created txt file

my Code

```
string File = Server.MapPath("") + "\\Batch\\create_text_file.bat";
Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("{0}", txt_text_file_name.Text.Trim());
proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Server.MapPath("") + "\\Batch\\";
proc.StartInfo.FileName = File;

try
{
    proc.Start();
    proc.WaitForExit();
    proc.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    this.lblError.Text = ex.Message;
}
finally
{
    txt_text_file_name.Text = "";
}
```

Inside batch file

```
@echo off
echo username="%~1" >>"E:\Testing\FTP_Management_system\Batch\test.txt"
```

if i write some with enter(new line) inside my textarea then its just showing the 1st line

means:if i write

```
hello 
world
```

then in txt file its writing only hello

how can i allow line break in text file.

Need output hello "line break" world.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use Environment.NewLine or "\n" in string.

Answer (score 0):

First separate your words somehow, then use this code after hello:

Environment.NewLine during your string.

e.g.

String = "Hello" Environment.NewLine "World"